# IE7 H1 tag not taking CSS style

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Is there a bug for IE7 (and below) with the H1,H2,H3 tags not taking CSS styles?

My styling works for IE8, FF, Chrome. Somehow IE7 is not taking the style into account.

This is my H1 style:

```
H1 {
font-weight:normal;
display:inline;
font-size:inherit;
}
```

All other browser works fine other than IE7 (and below).

Please help anyone?

Comment: Are all 3 of those properties not working?

Comment: i think a small example from you will help us to find the issue, as u are inheriting the font size. what exactly the cause is? can you post the css and html on jsfiddle

Comment: you mean <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> ? Yes this is my doctype.

Comment: IE7 doesn't support the value inherit for font-size. Is that what went wrong?

Comment: that doesnt justify why display and weight is not working as well

Comment: http://browsershots.org/screenshots/2aa752a52a4906a21e51fd286d467e28 here is a screenshot, notice the competitivte quotes and  connect with. thats my H1, and below the business service, home service, thats my H2. They are all not taking the css style.

Answer (score 2):

[W3Schools has the answer on its CSS font-size property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp) page:

> The font-size property is supported in all major browsers.
>
> The value "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier

Here's the computed h1 style in IE7. Notice that it's missing its `font-size` attribute.

You end up with:

- a font size of 36px, inherited from `div button`.
- a [`font weight:inherit`, which means nothing, as this is also not supported by IE7](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp).
- display inline from your page's inline h1 declaration

[image]

Comment: that doesnt justify why display and weight is not working as well

Comment: Thanks campbell, i will go back and do a check. will update :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in IE7.

http://jsfiddle.net/yV5uV/